# Why isn't my CollectionChanged event handler getting called?

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged, inotifycollectionchanged

I have done some research and other answers on stackoverflow indicate that I need to extend the ObservableCollection class to add PropertyChanged event handlers to each item when an item is added or removed in order to get events when the contents of an item in the collection change... a bit annoying really, but I've implemented this class based on some of those answers:

```
    public class DeeplyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DeeplyObservableCollection()
        : base()
    {
        CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(DeeplyObservableCollection_CollectionChanged);
    }

    void DeeplyObservableCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Object item in e.NewItems)
            {
                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Object item in e.OldItems)
            {
                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }
            
    }

    void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs a = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        OnCollectionChanged(a);
    }
}
```

As I understand it, the CollectionChanged event will be fired when ever one of the elements fires a PropertyChanged event. This seems to work when I step through the code as I do get stepped into the DeeplyObservableCollection_CollectionChanged method from the item_PropertyChanged method.

So in my code I attach an event handler to the DeeplyObservableCollection_CollectionChanged method like this:

```
GroupSettingsList.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(this.ContentCollectionChanged);
```

GroupSettingsList is a DeeplyObservableCollection and ContentCollectionChanged is a CollectionChanged eventhandler. I don't get any errors but my method never gets called and I'm not sure why.

What do I need to do to get my event handler to be called here?

#### Additional Code showing how I use this class:

```
    class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    private DeeplyObservableCollection<GroupSettings> _groupSettingsList;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
    GroupSettingsList = new DeeplyObservableCollection<GroupSettings>();

    GroupSettingsList.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(this.ContentCollectionChanged);

    // Have also tried this:
    // _groupSettingsList.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(this.ContentCollectionChanged);
}

public class GroupSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isDisplayed;

    public bool IsDisplayed
    {
        get { return _isDisplayed; }
        set
        {
            _isDisplayed = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsDisplayed");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public DeeplyObservableCollection<GroupSettings> GroupSettingsList
{
    get { return _groupSettingsList; }
    set
    {
        _groupSettingsList = value;


          this.OnPropertyChanged("GroupSettingsList");
        }
    }

    private void ContentCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoSomething(); // This never executes.
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code and the CollectionChanged handler was fired as expected, both when the collection itself was changed and when a property of the underlying object in the collection was changed. What code were you using to change the object's property?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Try unsubscribing only on e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove

Comment: I am changing the code from a bound to a check box. Both trace output and stepping through the debugger show that the two way binding is working and that the CollectionChanged event handler within my DeeplyObservable class get fired (i.e. DeeplyObservableCollection_CollectionChanged). I have tried subscribing to the event on both the GroupListSettings property as well as the _groupListSetting backing field with the same result. I have updated my question with more code showing how I'm using these classes. Hopefully someone sees my error...

Comment: Shouldn't class MyViewModel be a public class?

Comment: I've changed it to public with no difference. All of these classes are in the same assembly so the default internal was probably working the same as an explicit public.

Comment: Is the problem that the items in your UI aren't being updated when items are added, removed or changed? E.G. your collection is bound to a ListBox but it does not reflect your changes.